# Large file size image upload issue in wordpress comments

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website. I'm unable to upload images (larger than 1MB) in the comment section of the website post. But images with small file size (lesser than 1MB) is getting uploaded. I have tried updating the .htaccess and multiPHP ini Editor but its not helping. Here's my .htacess code

```
<IfModule php5_module>
php_flag asp_tags Off
php_flag display_errors Off
php_value max_execution_time 30
php_value max_input_time 60
php_value max_input_vars 1000
php_value memory_limit 32M
php_value post_max_size 15M
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
php_value upload_max_filesize 15M
php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
php_flag client_max_body_size 20M;
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you on a local machine or is this on a webhost server somewhere?  I'm not familiar with setting PHP environment variables via .htaccess. Have you tried updating those same values in your php.ini file in your site's root directory?  In particular, bumping the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize should fix it if the problem is indeed a PHP configuration issue.

Comment: webhost server. I have tried the values in php.ini.

Comment: I'd probably try making sure that your php config settings are actually taking effect.  Somewhere in a WordPress or theme file try dumping the value of one of your settings and see if it matches. Like: var_dump(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));  If the value there is different, then you'll need to contact your webhost and get their help.  If the values are correct, then something else is going on.

Comment: You might want to check your PHP version.  Your apache directives are set to look for php5 and if you're running 7.x they're not going to work.